# scipy linregress: computing support and resistance trendlines on timeseries

Tags: python, scipy, linear-regression

I would like to compute the trendlines (support and resistance) on timeseries charts (like stocks).
I have manage to assemble something fairly simple that works in many cases, but not in all.
In  my example for the stocks 'ENZ' and 'ARTL' we could imagine better trendlines.
Could anyone familiar with scipy linregress help me improve it / find what goes wrong for some stocks?
The full code is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import linregress
import time
import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta  

df = pd.DataFrame()

for ticker in ['SNN','AAPL', 'ENZ', 'ARTL']:

    #1# Get data
    print('Processing ticker '+ str(ticker))
    df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start = '2020-09-01', end = '2021-09-01', interval = "d")
    df['Ticker'] = ticker #adds the ticker name
    print(df)

    #2# Compute support and resistence trendlines based on df['Close']
    df_len = len(df)
    df['Number'] = np.arange(df_len)+1
    df_high = df.copy() #resistance
    df_low = df.copy()  #support
    #resistance
    while len(df_high)>2:
        slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = linregress(x=df_high['Number'], y=df_high['Close'])
        df_high = df_high.loc[df_high['Close'] > slope * df_high['Number'] + intercept]
    df['resistance'] = slope * df['Number'] + intercept    
    print( '\tresistance:\t' + ' slope: ' + str(round(slope, 3)) + '\tintercept: '+ str(round(intercept,3)))
    #support
    while len(df_low)>2:
        slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = linregress(x=df_low['Number'], y=df_low['Close'])
        df_low = df_low.loc[df_low['Close'] < slope * df_low['Number'] + intercept]       
    df['support'] = slope * df['Number'] + intercept
    print( '\tsupport:\t' + ' slope: ' + str(round(slope,3)) +'\tintercept: '+ str(round(intercept,3)))


    #3# Plot
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))
    color = 'tab:green'
    xdate = [x.date() for x in df.index]
    ax1.set_xlabel('Date', color=color)
    ax1.plot(xdate, df.Close, label="indi", color=color)
    ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor=color)
    ax1.legend()
    ax2 = ax1.twiny()
    ax2.plot(df.Number, df.resistance, label="resistance")
    ax2.plot(df.Number, df.support, label="support")
    plt.title(label=df['Ticker'][1])
    plt.legend()
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same code in my stock algo. I was having some problems with this line:

```
df_high = df_high.loc[df_high['Close'] > slope * df_high['Number'] + intercept]
```

because df_high was reducing down to only one row. Scipy won't calculate a slope for only one record so `NaN` was returned. I solved it like this:

```
if len(df_high.loc[df_high['Close'] > slope * df_high['Number'] + intercept]) > 1:
    df_high = df_high.loc[df_high['Close'] > slope * df_high['Number'] + intercept]
else:
    break
```

Also, I don't use yahoofinance, but make sure you're not getting current day values equal to zero. That'll mess up a slope quickly. It happened to me when pulling live data from TDAmeritrade if the market hasn't opened yet.